Render dont work - Rendered image cuts off the edges

Hey guys i have a  problem with my render image. I rendered a 48-frame sequence in Cycles. In the normal view, everything looks correct, but when I render with the background, it cuts off the edges in an unusual way. The camera is set to 17.2 mm.

This looks like some sort of fisheye effect. Can you add a screenshot of your Compositor?
